# getY() behaviour is incorrect?

Tags: android

I have doubts that coordinates from `Event`s are right.

My application have single `Activity` instance with root `FrameLayout` element in its layout. I'm working on Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.0.2, but am writing application for Android 1.6 API.

Now to the production of this:

Let's override `onTouch()` callback on `FrameLayout` instance and add this logger (`e` stands for `event`):

```
Log.i("a",String.valueOf(e.getY()-e.getRawY())
        +" "+String.valueOf(e.getY())
        +" "+String.valueOf(e.getRawY()));
     );
```

Then we check what the output is:

```
06-03 16:31:50.560: I/a(15480): 0.0 676.4715 676.4715
06-03 16:31:51.326: I/a(15480): 0.0 675.4723 675.4723
06-03 16:31:51.380: I/a(15480): 0.0 680.4684 684.4653
06-03 16:31:51.388: I/a(15480): -100.0 584.4653 684.4653
06-03 16:31:51.412: I/a(15480): 0.0 686.4637 686.4637
06-03 16:31:51.412: I/a(15480): 0.0 686.4637 686.4637
```

See strange fluctuation in fourth stroke? Interesting that "100.0" is exactly the height of upper Android OS menu graphical elements (in my case). These "100.0" can be obtained from the app in this way:

```
float padding = act.instance.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight()
                -fl.getBottom();
```

, where `act` is `Activity`'s instance and `fl` is `FrameLayout`'s one.

I can add that if we draw something on layout with second value (`e.getY()`) from fourth stroke, it'll be right under finger. With third value it will be pretty lower than finger. So I conclude that system supplies me with wrong values of touch y-coordinate most of the time, and sometimes suddenly tells me right one.

My current workaround for this is only listen to `e.getRaw()` and subtract Android upper-screen elements height computed above.

So the questions are:

1. Have anyone encountered this? Maybe run this logger and check what it prints on your configuration?
2. If your configuration is affected, do you know what causes it? Maybe you can tell more elegant workaround?

Thank you for your attention!